# Using console as tab

Tags: linux, vim

I have several cpp source files in tabs in vim. I would like to have another tab with command prompt in order to run make. I open net tab , run sh and now I have console. But how to move from this console to other tabs? If I press `ctrl+page up` I have garbage in console and no tab change. How to move to another text tab when staying in console tab?

Comment: Which terminal program?

Comment: I run sh command. I suppose it is called bash

Comment: vim 8 has a terminal emulator. http://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html

Comment: Currently I'm using vim 7.4 on Ubuntu 16 04. What is the best way to get vim 8 ?

Comment: Are you using terminal? I would use `tmux` for this instead of builtin terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, vim 8 or neovim both have an terminal emulator in it.

Since you are using vim 7 here are some other ways:

[Tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) as @wizzup mentioned is perfect for this use-case. I think it is the most used Terminal-Multiplexer and extremly mighty. It is complex in comparison but since you are using vim, a steep learning curve should not be a killer point. However there are a few cavehats but you will find thousands of articles to solve them.

[GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is an alternative to tmux, I have no experience with it, but should be usable pretty good with vim too.

With them you can use something like this [Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2711) which allows you to use the terminal in vim itself. However I haven't tested it but it seems to be rather groomed.